# Grunt-usemin: Not generating my new index.html but it is concatenating and minifying my scripts

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I need your help :)

I am trying to use usemin to build my angular app.
Basically I want to generate a new index.html that will have a reference to just one .js file that is properly minified.

The app.js file is being generated correctly, but my new index.html is not.

I am pretty new to grunt and usemin, but here is my gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json'),

    useminPrepare: {
      html: 'public/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: 'dist'
      }    
    },

    concat: {
      generated: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: '.tmp/concat/js/app.js',
            src: ['public/**/*.js', '!public/bower_components/**']
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      generated: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: 'dist/js/app.js',
            src: [ '.tmp/concat/js/app.js' ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }

  });

grunt.registerTask('build', [
'useminPrepare',
'concat:generated',
'uglify:generated',
'usemin'
]);
```

Here is the relevant section of my index.html:

```
<!-- build:js js/app.js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="domain/domain.js"></script>
<script src="domain/landingPage/landingPageController.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

My folder structure is:

```
+- public
|   +- index.html
|   +- domain
|       +- js files       
+- gruntfile
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: I use a very similar process, and the only major difference between mine and yours is i have a usemin option area in addition to useminPrepare. For simplicity i'll just post my gruntfile [here](http://pastebin.com/LKVBqLB6). The only major difference is i first copy all of the relevant files into the output folder, and the process them there rather than doing it in one step. That of course is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: @KevinB, I took your file as an example and managed to make my scenario work. Thanks a lot for the input!
I'll post my gruntfile at github as answer the question soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this [file](http://pastebin.com/LKVBqLB6) from @KevinB and created a simpler one that did what I wanted.
There are still some rough edges, but it does answer the question.

```js
    grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json'),

    clean: [ 'dist' ],

    copy: {
      build: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'public/',
            src: [ '**', '!**/**/*.js' ],
            dest: 'dist'
          }          
        ]
      }
    },

    processhtml: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            'dist/index.html': ['dist/index.html']
          }
        }
    },

    concat: {
      generated: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: 'dist/js/app.js',
            src: ['public/**/*.js', '!public/bower_components/**']
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    
    uglify: {
      generated: {
        files: [
          {
            dest: 'dist/js/app.js',
            src: [ 'dist/js/app.js' ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }    

  });
  
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    'copy',
    'processhtml',   
    'concat:generated',
    'uglify:generated'
  ]);
```

Comment: note, the processhtml method is of course unrelated, all it does is allow you to make changes to specific parts of a file, for example, changing the `<base>` between a production build and a dev build.

Comment: @rafael-audy-glanzner you should not need to override *:generated task. There are configured by `useminPrepare` using the build comment configuration.

Comment: My advice would be to copy html and all static assets to dist directory and then run useminPrepare, *min tasks, and then usemin.